# How to use c++ mfc CDHtmlDialog OnDocumentComplete to get http header

Tags: c++, http, mfc, header

I want to use mfc's CDHtmlDialog OnDocumentComplete to get http header,but unknow how to do

```
code:
void CUPayWindow::OnDocumentComplete(LPDISPATCH pDisp, LPCTSTR szUrl){
    //How to get http header?
}
```